# java BufferedReader specific length returns NUL characters

Tags: java, sockets

I have a TCP socket client receiving messages (data) from a server.
messages are of the type length (2 bytes) + data (length bytes), delimited by STX & ETX characters.

I'm using a bufferedReader to retrieve the two first bytes, decode the length, then read again from the same bufferedReader the appropriate length and put the result in a char array.

most of the time, I have no problem, but SOMETIMES (1 out of thousands of messages received), when attempting to read (length) bytes from the reader, I get only part of it, the rest of my array being filled with "NUL" characters. I imagine it's because the buffer has not yet been filled.

```
char[] bufLen = new char[2];
_bufferedReader.read(bufLen);

int len = decodeLength(bufLen);

char[] _rawMsg = new char[len];
_bufferedReader.read(_rawMsg);

return _rawMsg;
```

I solved the problem in several iterative ways:

- first I tested the last char of my array: if it wasn't ETX I would read chars from the bufferedReader one by one until I would reach ETX, then start over my regular routine. the
  consequence is that I would basically DROP one message.
- then, in order to still retrieve that message, I would find the first occurence of the NUL char in my "truncated" message, read & store additional characters one at a time until I reached ETX, and append them to my "truncated" messages, confirming length is ok.

it works also, but I'm really thinking there's something I could do better, like checking if the total number of characters I need are available in the buffer before reading it, but can't find the right way to do it...

any idea / pointer ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InputStream read method may return short reads; you must check the return value to determine how many characters were read, and continue reading in a loop until you get the number you wanted.  The method may block, but it only blocks until *some* data is available, not necessarily all the data you requested.

Most people end up writing a "readFully" method, like DataInputStream, which reads the amount of data expected, or throws an IOException:

```
static public int readFully(InputStream inp, byte[] arr, int ofs, int len) throws IOException {
    int                                 rmn,cnt;

    for(rmn=len; rmn>0; ofs+=cnt, rmn-=cnt) {
        if((cnt=inp.read(arr,ofs,rmn))==-1) { 
            throw new IOException("End of stream encountered before reading at least "+len+" bytes from input stream"); 
            }
        }
    return len;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample server that I have used for testing
The main rcv is structured like

```
while((chars_read = from_server.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    to_user.write(buffer,0,chars_read);
    to_user.flush();
}
```

The actual whole server is below ...

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      try
      {
         if (args.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of Args");

         String   host = args[0];
         int      port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

         Socket   s = new Socket(host,port);

         final Reader from_server = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
         PrintWriter to_server = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));

         BufferedReader from_user = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         final PrintWriter to_user = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

         to_user.println("Connected to " + s.getInetAddress() + ":" + s.getPort());

         Thread t = new Thread()
         {
            public void run()
            {
               char [] buffer = new char[1024];
               int chars_read;
               try
               {
                  while((chars_read = from_server.read(buffer)) != -1)
                  {
                     to_user.write(buffer,0,chars_read);
                     to_user.flush();
                  }
               }
               catch(IOException e)
               {
                  to_user.println(e);
               }

               to_user.println("Connection closed by server");
               to_user.flush();
               System.exit(0);
            }
         };

         t.setPriority(Thread.currentThread().getPriority() + 1);
         t.start();

         String line;
         while ((line = from_user.readLine()) != null)
         {
            to_server.println(line);
            to_server.flush();
         }

         //t.stop();
         s.close();
         to_user.println("Connection closed by client");
         to_user.flush();
      }
      catch(Throwable e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println("Usage : java TCPClient <hostname> <port>");
      }
   }
```