# Error reading from a socket in java

Tags: java, sockets

On the one side of the socket I know the data is going into the socket correctly.

I set up a connection:

```
Connection sr = new Connection();
Server server = new Server("NAME", Interger.parseInt(port));
server.setIp(ip);
sr.setServer(server); 

//I know my server connection code is correct because I can send and receive data in 
//other areas of my program just fine

InputStream is = null;

try
{
  is = sr.getChannel().socket().getInputStream();

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();

  int k =0;

  while(k != -1)
  {
    k = br.read();
    text.append((char) k);
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //no errors ever get thrown
}
```

And then I only get about half my data, 10989 bytes out of a total 21398 that I send.  The amount of bytes it reads varies but the data always ends with  `..., "values": ["` which in the data I send over looks like , `..., "values": ["", ""]`.

Comment: I doubt this is the cause of your problem but you should do something like while ((k =  br.read())!=-1) to avoid appending -1 to text at the end of the input

Comment: ah, yea I was originally doing  new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next(); but I put that in just to make sure I wasn't doing anything dumb.

Comment: do you flush the output on the sending side?

Comment: @jtahlborn Yea I close the socket, which flushes it.

Comment: does any other code consume data from this socket's inputstream?  (is this the _actual_ code or some "similar" code that you created for posting here?)

Comment: do you _flush_ the streams before closing?  and do you close from the top-level Writer?  if you close the socket OutputStream directly you may be losing data in a buffered Writer in a higher layer.

Comment: @jtahlbor thanks for your help, So on the other side of the socket is some c++, it all flushes and closes correctly im pretty certain of that.  This is the actually code that I use to read the data off the socket.

Comment: is the data that you are receiving "correct" (up to the point of truncation)?  i notice you are reading "characters", not "bytes".  is it possible you are dealing with multi-byte encodings and therefore just not calculating correctly (you should generally be using an explicit character set with your InputStreamReader)?

Comment: You don't need to flush streams before closing. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Keep reading until you have all the data.  This question has been showing up about once a week lately.  There's no guarantee that the network is going to have all your data show up at once.

You need to keep reading until you have all your data.  How do you know how much data was sent?  You should probably build a little protocol between the client/server that defines how much data is going to be sent, the server reads that little header and continues to read until the full message has been received.

Comment: the example code keeps reading until EOF.  not sure what your point is?

Comment: Well the point was that the server has no real idea how much data is supposed to be sent here, so there is no error when it gets a socket close.  You are on the right track though, it looks like a client issue to me.  A Similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687736/java-bufferedreader-specific-length-returns-nul-characters/2687928#2687928

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this could help you :

```
int k =0;

while((k = br.read()) != -1){
   text.append((char) k);
}
```

1) In your case it is making the check on the next `iteration`, which may lead to appending of non-representable character(`char` of -1) to the end of `text`.

2) Never leave `catch block` empty, may be there is some `execption`.

Comment: jtahlborn pointed this out to me in the main questions context... This is actually the third iteration of the inputstream read that I used just to debug and make sure it wasn't a reading problem.  First I used Scanner, then readLine and finally the byte read... and they all came out the same.  So I'm pretty sure I'm reading all the data that I have in the Inputstream correctly.

Comment: i have made a check, there is no problem in your reading, just make sure to close the streams, good luck..

Answer (score -1):

So because my sending side of the socket was in c++ I was accidentally passing in a null ASCII value into the socket.  And it is undocumented on the java side of the socket that if the read encounters a null value it treats it as an end of file.  So it was prematurely ending the stream because it hit the null.

Comment: "undocumented" in your code?  java doesn't treat null characters specially.

Comment: If you send a null char over a socket, when you read the null(ascii 0) it will terminate your reading because it thinks that is your EOF.  At least thats what im seeing.

Comment: no, java does not see the null character as special, that's what i'm saying.  it should return it like any other character.

Comment: Hmmm thats what I thought was going on.  I look at where in the socket read it kicks out and it does it right at null.

Comment: you are looking at java code?  can you point me to the code you are looking at?  and when you say "null", do you mean the java value `null` or the byte with value 0?  btw, c/c++ treats the null character as "end of string", is it possible that on the _sending_ side you aren't sending all the data?

Comment: @EJP which part of this isn't an answer? The problem that I described was solved when I realized this.  The only reason I posted was to help other people that might run into this same problem.  Your downvotes and comments make me not want to do that.

Comment: @jtahlborn I mean the byte value 0 which is an ASCII null.  And I can read the same data over the socket in c++, so I'm sure that it's the java side that is being weird.  But thank you for your ideas/help.

Comment: if java could not read a null byte over a socket, java would never be able to download any arbitrary binary data (which may be riddled with null bytes).  and i _know_ java can do this.  so, i'm not sure what code has led you to believe that java stops reading data at a null byte.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll try and see if I can make a test program that ends a stream on a null value.  But I could also be doing something stupid on the java side.  What I do know is that once I removed the nulls from the c++ input I was able to read all the data on the java-side output.